# Ajax load issues with space in url

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, mod-python

I have 2 python files: **gui.py** & **index.py**

**python.py** contains table with records from mysql database.

**gui.py** contains **python.py** and textfield with button to send messages.

Also, **gui.py** contains javascript that will load new **python.py** with parameters.

**gui.py script**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").load("http://localhost/index.py");
    $("button").click(function(){
        var url = "http://localhost/index.py?name=1&message=";
        var msg = document.getElementById("message").value;
        var res = url.concat(msg);
        alert(res); //here I always can understand that result URL is okay.
        $("#content").load(res);
    });
</script>
```

And **index.py part**

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `messages` (`sender`, `receiver`, `text`, `time`) VALUES ('" + req.form['name'] + "', '3', '" + req.form['message'] + "', now())")
});
```

Where `req` is from `def index(req):` **I am using mod_python**.

**So, the problem is** - when i try to send message with space is in - my table disappears (till next page refresh (but i don't need to refresh it without spaces, ajax load works good here)). And then I will see only the first word of the message. As you can see in my code, i have `alert(res);` if I copy that alert and just run that url - spaces works nicely.

**Some details**

I am using ubuntu 14.04, apache2, mod_python, python 2.7, mysql database, python-MySQLdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should URL encode the message body to protect against special characters in the URL, like, say, space.  If you did

```
var msg = encodeURIComponent( document.getElementById("message").value );
```

You may have better success.

Comment: Thank you. That works :)
Strange that I was trying to replace " " to "%20" and that give me null result :)